# python - macOS terminal ignoring /etc/paths for /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, terminal, python, path

I'm trying to install Homebrew with Python on a clean install of macOS High Sierra. HomeBrew successfully installed, as did python, pip etc into the /usr/local/bin folder and I've edited the `/etc/paths` to have `/usr/local/bin` at the top before `/usr/bin` but the terminal is still showing `/usr/bin` as the python version when using `which python`. I've tried restarting the terminal and system.

The exact same setup was working fine before I reinstalled the OS.

`/etc/paths` looks like this

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

EDIT: `echo $PATH` shows `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` but `which python` still shows `/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your system paths (in `/etc/paths`) is neither recommended nor needed.

If you've installed Python through Homebrew (`brew install python` and `brew install python3`), you should read the caveats carefully:

```
brew info python
brew info python3
```

#### Why is Homebrew's handling of `python` so special?

Check out the [Homebrew and Python](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html) documentation, as Homebrew creates quite a few symlinks in different places and uses the following convention:

> Homebrew provides one formula for Python 2.7.x and another for Python 3.x. The executables are organized as follows so that Python 2 and Python 3 can both be installed without conflict:
>
> - `python` points to the macOS system Python (with no manual `PATH` modification)
> - `python2` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed)
> - `python3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x (if installed)
> - `pip2` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x’s `pip` (if installed)
> - `pip3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x’s `pip` (if installed)

The reason for this is that you don't want `python` defaulting to Homebrew Python if it was installed as a dependency of some other formula, which could cause problems in scripts that simply use `/usr/bin/env python` in their shebang line.

Also note that this Homebrew/Python behavior may change at some point in the future, due to the legacy nature of Python 2.

#### But I want `python` to point to Homebrew's `python`!

So, if you really want to make `python` refer to Homebrew's Python 2.7 instead of your system Python, you should add that to your `$PATH` in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

... and leave your `/etc/paths` as they were before.

Comment: I'll do it that way. I'm still curious why it isn't working editing `/etc/paths` though since that's how it was setup before the system reinstall and I still have a MacBook Pro (also running High Sierra although with a upgrade from Sierra rather than reinstall) that has it setup with the `/etc/paths` edit.

Comment: Hm. To be honest, I don't know why it wouldn't work. Are you sure there's a `python` in `/usr/local/bin`? What does `which -a python` show?

Comment: Ah you're right. There isn't a `python` in `/usr/local/bin` only a `python2`, `python2.7`. The old systems presumably were setup with an older version of HomeBrew when a `python` was created in `/usr/local/bin`. Interestingly though there isn't a `python3` or does that have to be installed separately with HomeBrew? I thought they came bundle together with `brew install python`

Comment: No, you have to do `brew install python3` to get it.